Electron energy loss after collision with phonon
This paper considers the loss of energy when an electron scatters with a phonon. They write in Part C:

Assuming the phonon energy corresponds to the Debye temperature (
$\approx 0.03$ eV in Cu , and $\approx 0.02 \mathrm{eV}$ in Ag ), the
energy loss per collision can be averaged over (1) emission and absorption
according to the probabilities involved, (2) phonon emission corresponding
to an electron energy decrease equal to the phonon energy, (3) and phonon
absorption corresponding to an electron energy increase of the same
magnitude. In copper and silver at $300^{\circ} \mathrm{K}$, the average energy
loss per collision is $\approx 0.016 \ \mathrm{eV}$ and $\approx 0.0075 \ \mathrm{eV}$, respectively.

This seems like an unintuitive leap for me. I've added in the numbering in the brackets. I'm trying to follow:
For (1) I'm not sure how to determine this.
For (2) $T_{D,Cu}=348$K and $T_{D,Ag}=232$K so I can work out phonon emission energy. At temperatures lower than $T_{D}$ the phonon modes are not fully excited, but we are assuming all phonons are at $T_{D}$.
For (3)  Instead of emitting a photon, we now have $T_{D}$ plus some additional energy from the electron. But unclear how I determine this?
There is no explanation or citation, so I suspect it must be relatively straightforward.
